# get record from php with ajax and change ID attribute

Tags: php, ajax

i have a ajax and php as follows but it is not changing the value of html attribute with id #respo

is there any modification require?

```
$.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/shortfiles/loadans.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {reccount: reccount},
                        success: function(response) {
                         var response = ($response);
                                $("#respo").text(response);                  
                       },


                    })
```

and php as

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['reccount'];

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testsite");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt update query execution
$sql = "SELECT response from paper WHERE ID=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    $response => $row['response'];


}

echo json_encode($response);






// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

i want to assign a value of response to html element with id respo

Answer (score 0):

Your code must look like

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/shortfiles/loadans.php",
        success:function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        document.getElementById('elementName').value = obj.varaibleName;
        }
    });
```